# Behavior with primitive data types' value out of range & C99's PRI* macros

Tags: c

Say we have an 8-bit unsigned integer n (`UINT8_MAX=255`); what is the behavior of the compiler for `n=256`? Where can I find a table of default behavior when the value of a data type is out of range for different data types? Is there a pattern to how they behave when set out of range?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

uint8_t n = UINT8_MAX;
int main() {
  printf("%hhu ",n++);
  printf("%hhu",n);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling with `gcc -std=c99 -Wall *.c`, this prints: `255 0`

Also, is it acceptable to use C99's PRI* macros? How are they named?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`n=256;` converts the signed integer value `256` to `uint8_t`, then assigns it to `n`. This conversion is defined by the standard to take the value modulo-256, so the result is that `n` is set to `0`.

Not sure where you can find a table, but the rules for integer conversions are at 6.3.1.3:

> 1 When a value with integer type is
>   converted to another integer type
>   other than _Bool, if the value can be
>   represented by the new type, it is
>   unchanged.
>
> 2 Otherwise, if the new type is
>   unsigned, the value is converted by
>   repeatedly adding or subtracting one
>   more than the maximum value that can
>   be represented in the new type until
>   the value is in the range of the new
>   type.49)
>
> 3 Otherwise, the new type is signed
>   and the value cannot be represented in
>   it; either the result is
>   implementation-defined or an
>   implementation-defined signal is
>   raised

As AndreyT points out, this doesn't cover what happens when an out-of-range value occurs during a calculation, as opposed to during a conversion. For unsigned types that's covered by 6.2.5/9:

> A computation involving unsigned
>   operands can never overflow, because a
>   result that cannot be represented by
>   the resulting unsigned integer type is
>   reduced modulo the number that is one
>   greater than the largest value that
>   can be represented by the resulting
>   type.

For signed types, 3.4.3/3 says:

> EXAMPLE An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer overflow.

(indirect, I know, but I'm too lazy to keep searching for the explicit description when this is the canonical example of undefined behavior).

Also note that in C, the integer promotion rules are quite tricky. Arithmetic operations are always performed on operands of the same type, so if your expression involves different types, there are a list of rules to decide how to choose what type to do the operation in. Both operands are promoted to this common type. It's always at least an int, though, so for a small type like `uint8_t`, arithmetic will be done in an `int` and converted back to `uint8_t` on assignment to the result. Hence for example:

```
uint8_t x = 100;
uint8_t y = 100;
unsigned int z = x * y;
```

results in 10000, not 16 which would be the result if z were a `uint8_t` too.

*Also, is it acceptable to use C99's PRI* macros? How are they named?*

Acceptable to whom? I don't mind, but you might want to check whether your compiler supports them or not. GCC does in the earliest version I have lying around, 3.4.4. They are defined in 7.8.1.

If you don't have a copy of the C standard, use this: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf. It's a "draft" of the standard, released some time after the standard was published and including some corrections.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is described in the standard.

(*) **Unsigned** integer types implement modulo arithmetic. The modulo is equal to 2^N where N is the number of the value-forming bits in the type. This means that unsigned types "wrap around" on overflow (at both ends). If the maximum value of the type is 255, then 256 will turn into the next value after the wrap, which is 0.

The only exception from this behavior for unsigned types is when you convert a floating-point value to unsigned type. In case of overflow the behavior is undefined.

(*) **Signed** integer types are different. If the overflow occurs during *conversion* from floating-point type, the behavior is undefined (same as with unsigned types). If the overflow occurs during *conversion* from other integer type the result is implementation defined. If the overflow occurs during an arithmetic operation, the behavior is undefined.

(*) **Floating-point** types cause undefined behavior on overflow during conversion.